# Reverse Geocode Locations in Google My Maps (Custom Map Locations to Street Addesses)

Tags: google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2, google-location-services, mymaps

I have a custom map in [Google's "My Maps"](https://www.google.com/maps/about/mymaps/) with a list of locations. What is the easiest way to reverse geocode these to the street addresses? i.e. I would like to export the data as a list of locations + the associated addresses. The CSV export built in just exports the location names.

Answer (score 0):

From the map page's HTML (URL looks like: <s>`https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/edit?mid=.....`</s>`https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=XXXX`), you can first pull the `var _pageData = ....` JSON object (accessible on `window._pageData`).

From that you can pull the list of places with the associated [`place_id`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-id). These can then be resolved to the location info using the [`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json` API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details).